# How to controll size of image?

Tags: java, javascript, css, jsp

```
**css File**

#zDIV_slideShow a {color:#fff;background-color:#fff}
 #zDIV_slideShow {display:none;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat;text-align:center;margin:0;z-index:10IE Mac;}

**js File**


var TJK_gallery;
var TJK_anchor;
var TJK_itemNumber;
var TJK_stage;
var TJK_itemTitle;
var TJK_itemDescription;
var TJK_navPrev;
var TJK_navClose;
var TJK_navNext;
var TJK_zCounter;
var TJK_zImage;
function TJK_Gallery(zElement){
TJK_gallery=zElement;   
TJK_anchor = document.getElementById(TJK_gallery).getElementsByTagName("a");
// building the whole thing from scratch starting with the slideshow
// zDIV_slideShow
        var zDiv_wrapper = document.createElement('div');
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(zDiv_wrapper);
        zDiv_wrapper.id="zDIV_slideShow";
// zA_previous
        var zA_1 = document.createElement('a');
        var zImg_1 = document.createElement('img');     
        zDiv_wrapper.appendChild(zA_1);
        zA_1.id = "zA_previous";
        zA_1.title = "Previous Slide";
        zA_1.href = "#null";
        zA_1.appendChild(zImg_1);
        zImg_1.src="img/previous.gif";
        zImg_1.alt="Previous Slide";        
// zA_close     
        var zA_2 = document.createElement('a'); 
        var zImg_2 = document.createElement('img');     
        zDiv_wrapper.appendChild(zA_2);     
        zA_2.id = "zA_close";
        zA_2.title = "Back to the Gallery";
        zA_2.href = "#null";
        zA_2.appendChild(zImg_2);
        zImg_2.src="img/close.gif";
        zImg_2.alt="Back to the Gallery";
// zA_next      
        var zA_3 = document.createElement('a');
        var zImg_3 = document.createElement('img');
        zDiv_wrapper.appendChild(zA_3); 
        zA_3.id = "zA_next";
        zA_3.title = "Next Slide";  
        zA_3.href = "#null";
        zA_3.appendChild(zImg_3);
        zImg_3.src="img/next.gif";
        zImg_3.alt="Next Slide";
// zA_title     
        var zA_4 = document.createElement('a');
        zDiv_wrapper.appendChild(zA_4); 
        var zTitle = document.createTextNode("Title");
        zA_4.id = "zA_title";
        zA_4.appendChild(zTitle);       
// zDIV_counter
        var zDiv_counter = document.createElement('div');
        var TJK_zCounter = document.createTextNode("Keeping track");
        zDiv_wrapper.appendChild(zDiv_counter);
        zDiv_counter.id="zDIV_counter";
        zDiv_counter.appendChild(TJK_zCounter);
// zA_image     
        var zA_6 = document.createElement('a');
        var zImg_6 = document.createElement('img');
        zDiv_wrapper.appendChild(zA_6); 
        zA_6.id = "zA_image";
        zA_6.appendChild(zImg_6);
        zImg_6.id="zIMG";
// zA_description       
        var zA_5 = document.createElement('a');
        var zDescription = document.createTextNode("Description");
        zDiv_wrapper.appendChild(zA_5);
        zA_5.id = "zA_description"; 
        zA_5.href = "#";    
        zA_5.appendChild(zDescription);         
        for (var x=0,i=TJK_anchor.length;x<i;x++){
        TJK_anchor[x].onclick = badabingbadaboum;
// we create fragment identifier to be used to navigate and keep track of the items and we kick start the whole thing
        TJK_anchor[x].href = TJK_anchor[x].href+"#"+x;
// we create a container to receive the text links
        var zSPAN = document.createElement('span');
        TJK_anchor[x].appendChild(zSPAN);
        var zTextLink = document.createTextNode(TJK_anchor[x].title);
        zSPAN.appendChild(zTextLink);
        }
}   
function goPrevious() {
TJK_itemNumber = eval(document.getElementById("zA_title").hash.substring(1));
    // hiding the button if we are on first slide 
    if(TJK_itemNumber==1)this.className="transparent";
    TJK_navNext.className="nonOpaque";
    if(TJK_itemNumber==0){return} // we are at the beginning    
        TJK_zImage.src = TJK_anchor[TJK_itemNumber-1].href;
        TJK_zImage.alt = TJK_itemTitle.firstChild.data;     
        TJK_itemTitle.href = TJK_anchor[TJK_itemNumber-1].href;
        TJK_itemTitle.firstChild.data = TJK_anchor[TJK_itemNumber-1].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].alt;
        TJK_itemDescription.firstChild.data = TJK_anchor[TJK_itemNumber-1].title;
    // special care for this one in case there is no long description set       
    if(TJK_anchor[TJK_itemNumber-1].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].longDesc){
        TJK_itemDescription.href = TJK_anchor[TJK_itemNumber-1].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].longDesc;    
    // appendData() breaks IE5 Win
        TJK_itemDescription.firstChild.data=TJK_anchor[TJK_itemNumber-1].title+" [more info...]";
        TJK_itemDescription.title = "Follow this link for more Information";    
        TJK_itemDescription.className="noHand";
        TJK_itemDescription.style.textDecoration ="underline";
    }else{
        TJK_itemDescription.className="withHand";
        TJK_itemDescription.title="";
        TJK_itemDescription.href="#";
        TJK_itemDescription.style.textDecoration ="none";
        }
// we update the value of the counter in the DIV
var current = eval(document.getElementById("zA_title").hash.substring(1)) + 1;
TJK_zCounter.firstChild.data = "Item #"+current+" out of "+TJK_anchor.length;
}
function goNext() {
TJK_itemNumber = eval(document.getElementById("zA_title").hash.substring(1));
// hiding the button if we are on the last slide 
    if(TJK_itemNumber==TJK_anchor.length-2)this.className="transparent";
        TJK_navPrev.className="nonOpaque";
    if(TJK_anchor.length == TJK_itemNumber+1){return} // we are at the end  
        TJK_zImage.src = TJK_anchor[TJK_itemNumber+1].href;
        TJK_zImage.alt = TJK_itemTitle.firstChild.data;     
        TJK_itemTitle.href = TJK_anchor[TJK_itemNumber+1].href;
        TJK_itemTitle.firstChild.data = TJK_anchor[TJK_itemNumber+1].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].alt;
        TJK_itemDescription.firstChild.data = TJK_anchor[TJK_itemNumber+1].title;
// special care for this one in case there is no long description set       
    if(TJK_anchor[TJK_itemNumber+1].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].longDesc){
        TJK_itemDescription.href = TJK_anchor[TJK_itemNumber+1].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].longDesc;    
// appendData() breaks IE5 Win
        TJK_itemDescription.firstChild.nodeValue=TJK_anchor[TJK_itemNumber+1].title+" [more info...]";
        TJK_itemDescription.title = "Follow this link for more Information";    
        TJK_itemDescription.className
="noHand";
        TJK_itemDescription.style.textDecoration ="underline";
    }else{
        TJK_itemDescription.className
="noHand";
        TJK_itemDescription.title="";
        TJK_itemDescription.href="#";
        TJK_itemDescription.style.textDecoration ="none";
    }
// we update the value of the counter in the DIV
var current = eval(document.getElementById("zA_title").hash.substring(1)) + 1;
TJK_zCounter.firstChild.data = "Item #"+current+" out of "+TJK_anchor.length;   
}
// to make sure users don't follow the link in the title (it is there to be used as a match with the thumbnail that triggered the popup DIV)
function fakeIt() {return false}
// hiding the SlideShow
function hideTJK_stage() {
document.getElementById("zDIV_slideShow").style.height="0"; // IE5 Mac
document.getElementById("zDIV_slideShow").style.overflow="hidden"; // IE5 Mac
document.getElementById("zDIV_slideShow").style.display="none";
// we remove the opacity stuff
document.getElementById("wrapper").className="none";
// we set focus back to the thumbnail that triggered the "popup" DIV
var TJK_itemNumber = eval(document.getElementById("zA_title").hash.substring(1));
TJK_anchor[TJK_itemNumber].focus();
}
function badabingbadaboum() {
TJK_stage = document.getElementById("zDIV_slideShow");
TJK_itemTitle = document.getElementById("zA_title");
TJK_itemDescription = document.getElementById("zA_description");
TJK_navPrev = document.getElementById("zA_previous");
TJK_navClose = document.getElementById("zA_close");
TJK_navNext = document.getElementById("zA_next");
TJK_zCounter = document.getElementById("zDIV_counter");
TJK_zImage = document.getElementById("zA_image").getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
// we do some opacity stuff
    document.getElementById("wrapper").className="transparent";
// IE5 Mac (phantom links)
// this.blur();
// this is to reset the fix for IE Mac (see statement in (hideTJK_stage())  
    TJK_stage.style.height="20%";
    TJK_stage.style.display="block";
    TJK_zImage.src = this.href.replace(this.hash,"");
    TJK_zImage.alt = this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].alt;
    TJK_zImage.onclick = hideTJK_stage;
// "style.cursor" breaks IE5
    TJK_zImage.className = "hand";
    TJK_zImage.title = "Back to the Gallery";
// the href value we set for this anchor will be used to give focus back to the appropriate thumbnail 
    TJK_itemTitle.setAttribute("href",this.href);
// since we have a real href value in there we don't want the user to trigger the link
    TJK_itemTitle.onclick=fakeIt;
// clicking on the close box will close the popup DIV
    TJK_navClose.onclick=hideTJK_stage;
// setting the action for the prev/next links
    TJK_navPrev.onclick=goPrevious;
    TJK_navNext.onclick=goNext; 
// now we can set focus for keyboard users
    TJK_navPrev.focus();
// setting the height - mainly for IE - the second one is for IE5
    TJK_stage.style.height = (document.documentElement.clientHeight > 0) ? document.documentElement.clientHeight+"px" : document.body.clientHeight+"px";
// setting the width for IE 5 so there is no gap near the scrollbar
    if(document.documentElement.clientHeight == 0)TJK_stage.style.width=document.body.clientWidth+"px" ;
// setting the title and description
        TJK_itemTitle.firstChild.data = this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].alt;
        TJK_itemDescription.firstChild.data = this.title;
// if there is a long description in there, we use it as href value of the short description and we give it a title to. If there is none we make sure we reset values previously set and we do not let the user follow the "empty" link
    if(this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].longDesc){
        TJK_itemDescription.href = this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].longDesc;    
// appendData() breaks IE5 Win
        TJK_itemDescription.firstChild.data=this.title+" [more info...]";
        TJK_itemDescription.title = "Follow this link for more Information";    
    }else{
        TJK_itemDescription.removeAttribute("href");    
        TJK_itemDescription.title = ""; 
}
// we set the starting values for the "counter"
var current = eval(TJK_itemTitle.hash.substring(1)) + 1;
TJK_zCounter.firstChild.nodeValue = "Slide #"+current+" out of "+TJK_anchor.length; 
// hiding the button when everything "loads" depending on which slide we are on
// first we reset both buttons in case they have been turned off last time the user left the slideshow
TJK_navNext.className="nonOpaque";
TJK_navPrev.className="nonOpaque";
TJK_itemNumber = eval(document.getElementById("zA_title").hash.substring(1));
    if(TJK_itemNumber==0){
        TJK_navPrev.className="transparent";
        TJK_navNext.className="nonOpaque";
    }
    if(TJK_itemNumber==document.getElementById(TJK_gallery).getElementsByTagName("a").length-1){
        TJK_navNext.className="transparent";
        TJK_navPrev.className="nonOpaque";
    }
return false;   
}


**in jsp**

 <ul id="gallery" >
    <li><a name="zGallery"  href="img/NNG.jpg"><img src="img/noida.png"  /></a></li>
    <li><a href="img/002.jpg"><img src="img/gurgaon.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a  href="img/003.jpg"><img src="img/bhiwadi.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a  href="img/004.jpg"><img src="img/sohna.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="img/005.jpg"><img src="img/YamunaExpressway.png" width="260" /></a></li>

  </ul>
```

i am using a image as a link so when you click new image will open on top of current page.
i want to control the size of image.I have high pixel image so it covers all my page even more. So what change or extra code i need to use to control the size of image.....

Comment: You should have put only relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example for you that I have a div(width:500, height: 300) will contain the image and the image(1000px x 500px) like this:

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 300px;" id="container">
    <img src="yourUrl" id="image"/>
</div>
```

In javascript I'll do like this:

```
document.getElementById('image').onload = function(){
  if(this.naturalWidth > this.naturalHeight){
    this.style.Width = document.getElementById('container').style.Width + " !important";
    this.style.Height = "auto !important"; 
  }
  else{
    this.style.Height = document.getElementById('container').style.Height + " !important";
    this.style.Width = "auto !important"; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `height` and `width` of an image based on pixels or percentage.

Eg: `<img src="image.jpg" style="width: 50%; height: 50%"/>`

Comment: Its not working.In this way i can control my image size which is i am using for link. But when i click on the image a new image will say  <li><a href="img/002.jpg"><img src="img/gurgaon.png" /></a></li>  i want to control 002.jpg. which will open after i click on gurgaon .jpg

Comment: When you click on the image it shows the actual image and the rendering is managed by browser. If you want to show smaller image then you may re-size image at server side.